# Integral to discover limited area

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need to calculate the area limited by:

$y= x^3$

$y= -x+2$

$y= 0$

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtaY4.jpg)

I believe I need to separate into 2 integrals as these two lines intersect in one point, if that's correct how do I calculate the X value for that intersection without checking in a graphic calculator?

I did the integrals like this but i get the wrong solution, what am I doing wrong?

$\int_{0}^{1}(-x+2)-x^3 dx + \int_{1}^{2}x^3-(-x+2)dx$

Comment: In determining area between functions the integrand should be: "upper function - lower function". For the first integral "0 to 1" the upper one clearly should be x^3 and the lower 0 but your's isnt. For the "1 to 2" integral the upper function should be the line but instead it is the cubic x^3 . Essentially the functions you integrate over don't match the area your're describing.

Comment: So the integrals should be like this? $\int_{0}^{1}(x^3)-0 dx + \int_{1}^{2}(-x+2)-0dx$ ?

Comment: Yes, though writing out the substraction by 0 is essentially unnecessary.